# Selection of an isolation table

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vibration, sound-isolation

I need to conduct nano-indentation within a glovebox of a split-test cell for battery testing. I know that vibration may be a potential issue, and I should probably buy an isolation table. However, I do not know how to select the proper isolation table for this application. Does anyone have any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to give an exact answer, but here are a few things you may want to consider:

1. Do you want to place the isolation table inside the glovebox or outside it? On the outside, it will isolate building vibrations, but soundwaves hitting the glovebox surface and anyone touching it will still cause movements. On the inside, however, you are heavily limited by the size of the box.
2. How much space and weight do you have available? Very sturdy isolation tables may need reinforced floor and will be difficult to move into the room. However, making the table heavier is the easiest way to improve the vibration isolation.
3. How much isolation do you need? This is the hardest part to estimate, and isolation table manufacturers use several ways to report attenuation performance. One way is just to try it out: if you need more isolation, add another isolation device on top of the previous one.